# How to iterate array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lt1bpma/)

Here is my array looks like

```
var arr = [];
arr['alpha'] = {'a':'1','b':'1'};
arr['beta'] = {'a':'2','b':'4'};
console.log(arr)
```

When i take `console.log(arr.length)` It says 0. So i can't able to for loop this one

How can i iterate this array ?

**Note :**

I don't want to use jquery, i prefer only javascript

Comment: You can't have named keys for your array. (Technically, you can, but what you're really doing is assigning properties to your array, which is my JS is telling you the array has no length).  Instead, consider using an `object` for this purporse.

Comment: Ah, i got it, its not pushing, i am just assigning keys to my array

Comment: @SA__ You need to either use an integer index for your array, or switch to using an object.. ex: `var obj = {};` instead of `[]`.

Comment: You can get an array ok keys by doing `Object.keys(arr["alpha"])` which you can iterate